# how to load the data from a firestore 'get' into variables?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am upgrading to Angular v5 and to firestore and I am having a lot of problems extracting the fields from the firestore data.

I do not want to use angularfire2 because of the problems I had with it when Angular 4 was released.

About 10 days ago I spent a long time figuring out how to get data from a snapshot. In the end I got the code below to do it. Unfortunately "doc.data()['languageName'];" does not work with "get".

```
 querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
    let name = doc.data()['languageName']; 
    lang.push(name);
  });
});
```

After working all day on this I have decided to ask for help. My latest attempt is below.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(staff => {
    if (staff.emailVerified) {
      this.result = this.db.collection("staff").doc(staff.uid).get()
       .then(function(staffDb) {                 // staff.uid works
         if (staffDb.exists) {      // <--  Works to here
           this.sid = staffDb.data.sid;          // nor staff.sid 
           this.staff2memoryService.set(staffDb.data());
           this.staff = this.db.collection("staff").
                                 doc(this.sid).get()
           .then(result => {
              if (this.sid) {
                this.staff2memoryService.set(result);
              } else {
                console.log('Not exist');
              }
```

When I do a console.log all the data I want is there but I just cannot get at it. The firebase documentation shows how to access the fields using console.log but that does not help because console.log seems to automatically extract/map the fields.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this yesterday using "this.data" without success but the following works.

```
    if (staffDb.exists) {  
      var data = staffDb.data();
      var eid = data.eid;
```

Sometimes it is best to sleep on a problem, many hours yesterday a few minutes today. I am getting old!